# Trying to build a REST-Service with encapsulated http response codes

Tags: java, jax-rs, java-ee-5

I'm currently trying to build a REST webservice using Java/EE(5) that fully encapsulates the http responses, so every request should give back response code 200 (OK) and should look like this:

```
{   
    "msg" : { // imagine some datastructure here },
    "error" : {
        "code" : 200 // http response code
        "status" : "OK" // some string defining this
    }
}
```

My prefered framework is JAX-RS (we plan to migrate to EE6 soon, so migration is one of the topics while developing this), but can JAX-RS do this?

Comment: That is not REST. Why do you want to do SOAP again?

Comment: I'm confused, @LutzHorn. Where do you see SOAP here?

Comment: Don't embed the error code in the result but send it as an HTTP header.

Comment: @Rob In SOAP you the service always returns `200 OK`. The actual result of the request is embeded in the response body. That's what you are planning to do. That's not REST.

Comment: @LutzHorn, fiskeben: Ok, understood, but besides from doing bad style or doing a more SOAP-like approach, is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes. You can set both the response code, headers, and body to what you want with JAX-RS. Although I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @LutzHorn can you supply an simple example as an answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to always return `200 OK` and `Content-Type: application/json` with JAX-RS:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/not-rest")
@Produces("application/json")
public class NotRestBean {

    @GET
    public Response getSoapStyle() {
        String json = "{}"; // build your response here
        return Response.ok(json).build();
    }
}
```

Again, I don't recommend to do this. A central part of REST is the Uniform Interface which includes proper response codes.